# Powershell 5.1 parsing json for specific key, and writing its values as line delimited text into a new .txt file

Tags: json, powershell

In Powershell 5.1,  How do i parse the JSON below such that all the `xString` values are written into a new file > `output.txt` like below?

Desired output.txt:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Json to parse:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "retrievedObjects": [
      {
        "someName": "loremIpsum",
        "someBoolean": false,
        "anotherBool": false,
        "someString": "loremIpsum",
        "xString": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "childxStrings": [
          "CustomLabel"
        ],
        "someName": "loremIpsumABC",
        "someBoolean": false,
        "anotherBool": false,
        "someString": "loremIpsumYZY",
        "xString": "DEF"
      },
      {
        "someName": "settings",
        "someBoolean": false,
        "anotherBool": false,
        "someString": "settings",
        "xString": "GHI"
      }
    ],
    "someNamespace": "",
    "someSetting": false,
    "someOtherBool": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out `convertfrom-json`. Then you should be able to dot reference your properties like `$o.result.retrievedobjects.xstring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is parse the JSON file with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1), then convert JSON to a custom object with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$json = Get-Content -Path .\sample.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then use dot notation(as suggested by [@AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401175/powershell-5-1-parsing-json-for-specific-key-and-writing-its-values-as-line-del#comment115626945_65401175)) to access the nested `xString` property and output to a text file using [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$json.result.retrievedObjects.xString | Out-File -FilePath output.txt
```

You can also have a look at [Simplified Foreach Syntax in PowerShell 3.0](http://Understanding%20Simplified%20Foreach%20Syntax%20in%20PowerShell%203.0) for more information on the above syntax.
This was also introduced as [Member Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/#member-enumeration).